# Google calendar api v3 - undefined constructor error

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have got an access-token for Calendar API can't figure out how to use this token to manipulate the calendar.

I have already read their documentation and getting started guide but still need help. I used following code to create calendar service:

```
Calendar service = new Calendar(httpTransport, accessProtectedResource, jsonFactory);
service.setApplicationName("YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME");
```

but it says:

> The constructor Calendar(HttpTransport, GoogleAccessProtectedResource,
>   JacksonFactory) is undefined.

Comment: Did you include all needed libraries/packages? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup

Comment: yeah i have included all jars and dependencies and used the code given for app configuration in getting started guide,some of the classes are also deprecated. i  cant figure out how to use access token for creating client to interact with calendar api.

Comment: At last i have got the solution

Comment: used fallowing code to create client for calendar services    Calendar service = Calendar.builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory)
     .setHttpRequestInitializer(accessProtectedResource).build(); and it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Change constructor as shown below:

```
Calendar service = new Calendar(httpTransport, 
                                jsonFactory, 
                                accessProtectedResource);
```